# insert photo to same row in sqlite database from different class in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Android app, I want to insert user information to the same row in the SQLite database with their photo. I have two classes:

> Here MainActivity.Class

```
public void insertData(){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name",adisoyadigir.getText().toString());
    cv.put("user",kullaniciadigir.getText().toString());
    cv.put("password",sifregir.getText().toString());
    cv.put("school",okulgir.getText().toString());
    long id = mSQLiteDb.insert("student",null,cv);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The MainActivity class takes the user's name, surname, password, and school information. There is no problem here. Here is my second class, profilekranı.

> Here profilekrani.class

```
public void insertData(){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("photo",imageViewToByte(profilphoto));
    mSQLiteDb.insert("student",null,cv);
    Toast.makeText(profilekrani.this, "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private byte[] imageViewToByte(CircleImageView profilphoto) {
    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)profilphoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
    byte[] byteArray =stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

I can add the information and the photo I get from the user to the database. But the same row is not added, a new row is added.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, Photos are being added to the new row. I think the problem is in `mSQLiteDb.insert (" student ", null, cv)` but I can not solve it. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow

you need to update not insert the same row